# Germany: Professional accommodation for one month?

Tags: germany, accommodation

I'm being temporarily located in Bochum, Nordrhein-Westfalen, Germany for one month, for a work project.

My accommodation will be paid for by the company. I have the options of either booking a hotel for a month, or trying to find a house or apartment for short-term accommodation.

Spending a month in a hotel will drive me nuts. What's the best way to find a house or apartment for such a short period of time, and is this generally even possible?

The specific period of time is all of the coming February, so it's quite short-notice too.

Comment: Since your company will pay for the rent: Do you need a proper receipt suitable for accounting? If so, many of the private offers (subletting, etc) may be out of scope. What exactly do you miss in a hotel, which you expect to find in an apartment?

Comment: booking.com alone finds about 50 appartment rentals in the area around Bochum, which are available the entire month of February.

Answer (score 8):

You have a couple of options:

- Look at a meta-search engine such as Trivago.de -- They also have some non-hotels in their database
- Look on AirBNB. While the legality is sometimes questionable in Germany, that's not the problem of the renter.
- Look for vacation rentals. While Bochum is not exactly a place for vacation, there may be some nearby. Search engines such as Wimdu.de could be a starting point.
- Perhaps you may have a look at wg-gesucht.de -- This website is often used by students for offering rooms in flat-share communities for sub-letting while they are away (e.g., on an internship). Knowledge of German is highly useful there, though, and a month of rental may be too short for many offers.

The classical flat rental market is not what you want. Few landlords will be willing to offer a rental contract for this short time period, and the default style of renting a place in Germany is without furniture. Furnished apartments are quite unusual.

I do not have any connection to any of the mentioned websites (apart from having been a customer).

Comment: "the default style of renting a place in Germany is without furniture" - not to mention that it's often also without, or with only minimal light fixtures.

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is called **corporate housing**. They go by other names such as "serviced apartments". Basically it is short term accommodation, larger than a hotel room and with a kitchen and other facilities. It's specifically designed for people in your situation, where the stay is long enough to make being in a hotel troublesome but too short to be in the normal rental market, and where an employer is paying the costs. They are significantly larger than a hotel room, usually apartment sized or townhouse sized. They always come not just fully furnished but with everything you need to live a normal life, and often come serviced - i.e. they get cleaned on a regular basis. The price is usually less than a hotel but more than an apartment rental (though probably less than an apartment rental plus furniture etc.)

Places like this exist in most countries. Here is [a page talking about them specifically in Germany](https://www.howtogermany.com/pages/corporate-housing.html).

Comment: They often go by the name "Aparthotel" as well. If you don't mind not having your room cleaned every day they are actually a pretty good option for tourists sometimes, they can be the same or cheaper than an equivalent hotel room but with more space (for short stays, longer it's cheaper as there are usually price breaks). I stayed in one on a Hamburg city break with a group and it suited us fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you speak at least a bit of german, or can get someone who does to help you, you can check the following ressources:

- the major nationwide real estate web sites such as [immobilienscout24.de](https://www.immobilienscout24.de/), [immowelt.de](https://www.immowelt.de/), [immonet.de](https://www.immonet.de/)
- the housing market sections of local newspapers such as [ruhrnachrichten.de](https://immo.ruhrnachrichten.de/)
- [ebay Kleinanzeigen](https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/), the german equivalent to craigslist
- [wg-gesucht.de](https://www.wg-gesucht.de/en/) specialises on appartment-sharing and is even available in english (though the ads themselves might be available only in german)

Helpful keywords/categories are "möbliert" (ready-furnished) and especially "**Wohnen auf Zeit**" (living for a limited time, short-term rental). The latter almost always implies the former.

Furthermore, you can try directly typing "Wohnen auf Zeit" and "Bochum" into google (or whatever other general-purpose search engine you prefer), or even only "Wohnen auf Zeit", and enter "Bochum" as the next step into one of the web sites specialized  on short-term rentals turned up by the search.